ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Query timeout expired
I have multiple bots created with Uipath. Those bots are performing bulk update operations (I am using the activity) in the following table:

The database is located in a SQL server and my bots are executed from some Azure Virtual Machines. Both are located in the same region. Moreover, this table does not have a primary key and indexes, and it has 428.760 records in total.
The objective of the bulk update is to look for the column "id" and then update the column "document_hash".
This is the current connection string, I am using to perform the bulk update:
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=[myServer];Database=[myDatabase];Uid=[myUsername];Pwd=[myPassword];Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=300;

When bots are running in parallel sometimes I am getting the following error and additionally it takes more than one hour to update 270 records:

ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Query timeout expired

How could I solve this issue?.
I read I could implement index in the column "id" but also I read that it helps when querying data but not updating data.
UPDATE 1:
To give more information about the Uipath activity. I am using the "Bulk update" activity. This activity has a property called Bulk/batch update and in the [documentation][1] says:

Check this box to enable the creation of a temp table using Bulk
insert and to update using join between tables. Otherwise, bulk
updates are issued in batch.

By default is checked. I decided to disable this property in order to allow the update by batches. I still get a long updating time with this change. When I run only one bot, the update is faster, when I triggered more bots in parallel, then it seems there is a lock issue as @jdweng and @AlwaysLearning mentioned in comments. Is there any configuration or solution I can implement out of adding clustered indexes in the column "id"?.
[1]: https://docs.uipath.com/activities/other/latest/developer/bulk-update

How do you think sql server can update a row by id without querying for it? It's strange though that it takes such a long time, sounds like you have some unreleased transactions or something like that. Are you sure you only have 400k rows?

You may be having a locking issue when to parallel queries are trying to access the same  data.

I'd say race your horses and try adding the clustered index in your dev/QA environment. There aren't many locking strategies available to SQL Server on a heap.

@siggemannen you are right the update requires always an update. It was just a comment I found on Internet. Yes, I confirm the table has 400k rows. How do I know if my database has unreleased transactions with SSMS?.

DBCC OPENTRAN perhaps? It will show you the process with the transaction. You can use DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<SPID>) to see the original sql executed by that processID

I solved my issue by adding an clustered index (based on what @AlwaysLearning suggested). Appartently, when multiple bots want to update the database there is a lock. With the index, I was able to reduce the time from hour to few seconds. I leave here the sql statement I used to create the clustered index:
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_id
ON [TABLE_NAME] (id)

